# Spring Security need to redirect to Login Page on BadCredentialsException

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I am new to Spring Security.
I am facing one issue, I need error to get Displayed on Login page when Authentication fail for specific reason.

Also, I am authenticating user based on Web Service call to URL Configured.
Below is my configuration, Also I have configured `authentication-failure-handler-ref`

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/accessDenied.jsp">
    <security:form-login  login-page="/login.jsp" authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"
        default-target-url="/jsp/home"   />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp"
        access="permitAll" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/jsp/home"
        access="permitAll" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/jsp/*"
        access="isAuthenticated()" />


    <security:logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/login.jsp?logout=success" 
        invalidate-session="true"  />

</security:http> 

    <bean id="ldapAuthenticationProvider" class="com.on.transport.authentication.MyAuthenticationProvider">
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
         <security:authentication-provider ref='ldapAuthenticationProvider'/>   
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.service.CustomUserDetailsService">
    </bean>     

<bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException">/errorPage.jsp?login_error=1</prop>
            <prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.CredentialsExpiredException">/login.jsp?status=2</prop>
            <prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.LockedException">/login.jsp?status=3</prop>
            <prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException">/login.jsp?status=4</prop>     
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

When I write " authentication-failure-url" like below then everything works fine,

```
<security:http  ......>
        <security:form-login  login-page="/login.jsp"
            default-target-url="/jsp/home"  authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?status=1" />
                  ............
</security:http>
```

### But I need to configure in a way where I can check different type of Exceptions.

AuthenticationProvider

```
   public class MyAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;

        String username = auth.getName();
        String password = (String)auth.getCredentials();

        UserUpdated user = null;
        int status=0;
        try{
            status = webservice.authenticate(username, password); 
               //webservice is object one is used to authenticate

            if(status==1){
                List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthoritiesList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

                if(username!=null && (username.equals("test") || username.equals("jp@on.com"))){
                    grantedAuthoritiesList.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_ADMIN")); 
                }else{
                    grantedAuthoritiesList.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER"));
                }

                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, grantedAuthoritiesList);

            }else if(status==2){
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Incorrect Email Id or Password.");
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> authentication) {
        return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
    }
}
```

I am getting error message as:

```
HTTP Status 401 - Authentication Failed: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
```

instead I need is to redirect to Login page with error message.

I can see Logs as

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Incorrect Email Id or Password
    at com.on.transport.authentication.MyAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(MyAuthenticationProvider.java:98)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)

[AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.unsuccessfulAuthentication] - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
2013-09-07 13:05:42,685 DEBUG http-8080-2 [AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.unsuccessfulAuthentication] - Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
2013-09-07 13:05:42,686 DEBUG http-8080-2 [AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.unsuccessfulAuthentication] - Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler@3aabc1
2013-09-07 13:05:42,686 DEBUG http-8080-2 [SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure] - No failure URL set, sending 401 Unauthorized error
2013-09-07 13:05:42,686 DEBUG http-8080-2 [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.saveContext] - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2013-09-07 13:05:42,687 DEBUG http-8080-2 [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Please help me identifying what I am missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look here: http://www.codemarvels.com/2010/12/spring-security-3-how-to-display-login-errors/

To sum up, it says that you should capture in a controller the different mappings used in `authenticationFailureHandler`. Then you can redirect to any jsp and use the messages you need.